# Table View layout in xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard, tablelayout

I'm trying to manage a table view through the cell class. I would need to insert other objects in the hypothetical storyboard which should not only contain the table view, containing the list taken from the PHP API. When I configure the object and start the application this takes up the whole view even if there are other objects arranged .. thanks ..

[For example i would realize this layout with any labels in top of this storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5BwX.png)

[But when i building and run the application... it's the result..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGfIw.png)

Comment: What is your question?  Instead of describing your code, why don't you post the actual code so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: It is not a code problem but a layout, at least I believe in the code I have nothing to do with my problem because I manage the layout from the storyboard and being an application for iOS I have not used the XAML files. Place an image to show you how I would like it and how it comes out ..